# Left over mouse artefacts on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Tags: linux, linux-mint, mouse, display

Just installed a fresh copy of Mint 18.1 last evening on a new MSI CUBI-N. Works great and runs fine aside from one issue.

Whenever I hover over an active element and then move the mouse away again the pointer leaves ghost artefacts behind it. For a few seconds a second inactive pointer exists on the screen and there can be a number of them.

I have read about the VSync/Tearing options and I enabled the compositor option from the display menu but it seemed to make no difference. The driver manager reports that all is OK. I am using one driver for "Intel microcode firmware" but aside from that its all stock.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks.